# Can I do this integral using Bra-ket or Dirac notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

This comes from a physics problem, but I have a question about the math. Ill include what problem this came from at the bottom for context if necessary

**EDIT:** I should have been more clear originally, but what I really wnat to know is whether this is possible to do in Bra-kat or Dirac Notation, and how to go about that

Given: $\Psi(x,0)=A(2\psi_1(x)-i\psi_3(x))$ where $\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac {2} {a}} ~~ sin(\frac {n\pi x} {a})$

Find $\int_0^{{a/2}}|\Psi(x,0)|^2 dx$

$A=1/\sqrt5$

---

$\int_0^{{a/2}}|\Psi(x,0)|^2 dx=\int_0^{{a/2}}\Psi^*~\Psi~ dx$

**My Question:**

Is it possible to do this in a simpler way? Perhaps using dirac notation?

I tried $$(1/5)\langle \Psi|(2\psi_1-i\psi_3)|\Psi\rangle$$

If this is possible and the correct set up, how do I continue? Do I try to separate them? We just learned this week, so Im still pretty confused about it

If not possible to use, why?

---

---

Original Problem

At t = 0, a particle of mass m in an infinite square well with walls at
x = 0, x=a, is in a superposition of the (normalized) first and third stationary states
$$\Psi(x,0)=A(2\psi_1(x)-i\psi_3(x))$$
(a) What must A be in order for Ψ to be a normalized wavefunction?
$$A=1/\sqrt5$$
(b)  What is the probability that the particle is in the left half of the box
(i.e.,between x = 0 and x = a/2) at t = 0?

Hint: Instead of trying to do a complicated integral directly, notice that for odd n,$$\psi_n(x)=\psi_n(a-x)~\text{for}~0\leq x\leq a~
$$

Comment: The wave function is symmetric about the center of the interval so the probability that it is in the first hald is equal to the probability it is in the second half. In other words the answer is 1/2.

Comment: @Spencer but is it possible to do this using Bra-Ket or Dirac notation? I apologize for the misunderstanding, I should have been more clear about what I was asking in the original post

Comment: No you were totally clear, thats why my comment isnt an answer. The answer to your actual question is a bit complicatwd and it depends on how willing you are to bemd the defi itiom kf the braket notation. The basic answer is "no" because the standard notation would indicate integration over the entire interval. The complicated answer is "yes" if we define a new inner product on the odd numbered states only.